# What do these commands (`tar`) actually do? Is there a better way?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am going over some documentation pertaining to creating a distro repo. However, I cannot understand exactly what these commands perform:

```
# cd /mnt/
# ls
centos-1  centos-2  centos-3
# for i in 1 2 3 
> do
> cd /mnt/centos-$i
> tar cpf - . | ( cd /var/ftp/ks/centos/; tar xpf - )
> done
```

My (obviously incorrect) rundown of it is: Loop through every mounted CD (`/mnt/centos-<index>`) and create a `tar` of the folder preserving the permissions. Then, extract that `tar` file to another folder, again, preserving permissions.

If that is the case, why do it like this? Is there really not a better way? Or perhaps I'm missing the whole idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why tar (or cpio) is recommended over cp for this procedure is because of how the tools operate.

cp operates on each file object in turn, reading it from disk and then writing it in its new location. Since the locations of the source and destination may not be close on the disk, this results in a lot of seeking between the locations.

tar and cpio read as much as possible in one go, and then write it into the archive. This means that the source files will be read one after another and the destination files will be written one after another (allowing for process switching, of course), resulting in much less seeking and hence less time taken.

Comment: Taking all the buffering that's going on, `cp` and `tar` operate essentially identically: read some stuff until RAM gets nearly saturated, then write some stuff, and repeat. Do you have benchmarks that show a significant speed advantage to tar over cp?

Comment: @Gilles: The buffering may or may not be happening; FWIW, the fwrite()s could very well be fully synchronous for that particular mountpoint. Using `tar` would abstract this away somewhat - but in practice, I agree that buffering will erase the difference in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

The command performs an exact archive-like copy of a directory sub-tree (i.e. where tar preservers permissions, owner-ship, links etc.).

First, it the command

```
tar cpf - . | ( cd /var/ftp/ks/centos/; tar xpf - )
```

is equivalent to

```
tar cpf - . | tar -C /var/ftp/ks/centos -x -p -f -
```

where `-C` specifies the working directory tar should change to before starting to extract the files.

Probably, the colleague just was not aware of the `-C` option.

Also kind of equivalent is:

```
cp -a * /var/ftp/ks/centos/
```

(where `-a` or `--archive` stands for -r --preserve=all --no-dereference --preserve=links, i.e. cp preserves then permissions, copies recursively etc. like one expects when doing an exact archive-like copy)

It is not equivalent because the shell pattern matching `*` does not catch the dot-files in the current working directory. With a different source pattern the reason to choose `tar` over `cp -a` is that `cp -a` is a GNU extension and not POSIX, i.e. a `tar` solution would be a more portable one.

There are no performance reasons for choosing `tar` over cp.